# How can I handle text overflow in a DropdownMenuEntry?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app that uses a `DropdownMenu`. Some of the `DropdownMenuItems` have a `label` that is quite long. I would like to be able to truncate the labels with something like an ellipsis, or having the label fade out.

**Example code for an app to reproduce this:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  List<DropdownMenuEntry> entries()
  {
    var entries = <DropdownMenuEntry>[];
    entries.add(const DropdownMenuEntry(value: "foo", label: "This is extremely long and exceeds the bounds of the dropdown menu"));
    return entries;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                body: DropdownMenu(
                  width: 200,
                  dropdownMenuEntries: entries()
                )
            )
        )
      );
  }
}
```

**This results in an exception that looks like this:**

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 67 pixels on the right.
```

[image]

==============================================================

**What I have tried:**

Using `DropdownMenu.menuStyle`:

```dart
DropdownMenu(
  menuStyle: const MenuStyle(maximumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(200,200))),
  width: 200,
  dropdownMenuEntries: entries()
)
```

Using `DropdownMenuEntry.style`:

```dart
DropdownMenuEntry(
    value: "foo",
    label: "This is extremely long and exceeds the bounds of the dropdown menu",
    style: ButtonStyle(
      maximumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(200,200)),
      textStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll(TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))
    )
)
```

Despite trying these other options, I have been unable to resolve the overflow exception.

I have found a GitHub issue that seems related:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126882

But I have not found any workable solutions here either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **mater** channel Based on Flutter 3.14.0-14.0.pre.282 Dart SDK 3.2.0-140.0.dev 
I have tested with DardPad 
You can use new attribute **labelWidget**
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/133491/files#diff-9d50382c9ccb6db7df1b033920a77e417357a25d3dc1c7b8e09766a4df3a8998

code snippet

```
DropdownMenuEntry(
          value: "foo",
          labelWidget: Text(labelText, maxLines:3, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          label:
              labelText),
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  List<DropdownMenuEntry> entries() {
    String labelText = "This is extremely long and exceeds the bounds of the dropdown menu";
    String labelText1 = "This is extremely long test and exceeds the bounds of the dropdown menu";
    var entries = <DropdownMenuEntry>[];
    entries.add(
      DropdownMenuEntry(
          value: "foo",
          labelWidget: Text(labelText, maxLines:3, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          label:
              labelText),
    );
      entries.add(
      DropdownMenuEntry(
          value: "bar",
          labelWidget: Text(labelText1, maxLines:3, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          label:
              labelText1),
    );
    return entries;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                body:
                    DropdownMenu(width: 200, dropdownMenuEntries: entries()))));
  }
}
```

Test result

[image]

Comment: I'm still relatively new to Flutter, and I didn't realize there were different channels that could be used. With the version I had, `labelWidget` was not an option. After upgrading to the channel you specified (minus the typo), I do see it. Thank you.

Comment: The current stable Flutter release (3.19) also has `labelWidget`. I don't know for how long it has, but folks do NOT need to switch to the less-stable `master` branch of Flutter.